# Add(3)(5) nn.Sequential. How it works?

Tags: python, pytorch

```py
class Add(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = value

    def forward(self, x):
        return x + self.value

calculator = nn.Sequential(
    Add(3),
    Add(2),
    Add(5),
)


x = torch.tensor([1])
output = calculator(x)
print(output) # tensor([11])
```

I made Add Model. but I can't understand how 'nn.Sequential' works.

at the firsttime, I understood like this

```py
add = Add(torch.tensor([1]))
add(3) # tensor([4])
add = Add(add(3))
add(2) # tensor([6])
add = Add(add(2))
add(5) # tensor([11])
```

but Add(3)(1) also works.
I can't understand why 'Add(3)(1)' works. help me plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand it right, the `Sequential` class in a nutshell just calls provided modules one by one. Here's the code of the forward method

```py
    def forward(self, input):
        for module in self:
            input = module(input)
        return input
```

here, `for module in self` just iterates through the modules provided in a constructor (`Sequential.__iter__` method in charge of it).

Sequential module calls this method when you call it using `()` syntax.

```py
calculator = nn.Sequential(
    Add(3),
    Add(2),
    Add(5),
)
output = calculator(torch.tensor([1]))
```

But how does it work? In `python`, you could make objects of a class *callable*, if you add `__call__` method to the class definition. If the class does not contain this method explicitly, it means that it possibly was inherited from a superclass. In case of `Add` and `Sequential`, it's `Module` class that implements `__call__` method. And `__call__` method calls 'public' `forward` method defined by a user.

It could be confusing that python uses the same syntax for the object instantiation and function or method call. To make a difference visible to the reader, `python` uses naming conventions. Classes should be named in a CamelCase with a first capital letter, and objects in a snake_case (it's not obligatory, but it's the rule that better to follow).

Just like in you example, `Add` is a class and `add` is a *callable* object of this class:

```py
add = Add(torch.tensor([1]))
```

So, you can call `add` just like you have called a calculator in you example.

```py
>>> add = Add(torch.tensor([1]))
>>> add(2)
Out: tensor([3])
```

But that won't work:

```py
>>> add = Add(torch.tensor([1]))
>>> add(2)(1)
Out: 
----> 3 add(2)(1)
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

That means that `add(2)` returns a `Tensor` object that does not implement `__call__` method.

Compare this code with

```py
>>> Add(torch.tensor([1]))(2)
Out:
tensor([3])
```

This code is the same as the first example, but rearranged a little bit.

--

To avoid confusion, I usually name objects differently: like `add_obj = Add(1)`. It helps me to highlight a difference.

If you are not sure what you're working with, use functions `type` and `isinstance`. They would help to find out what's going on.

For example, if you check the `add` object, you could see that it's a callable object (i.e., it implements `__call__`)

```py
>>> from typing import Callable
>>> isinstance(add, Callable)
True
```

And for a tensor:

```py
>>> from typing import Callable
>>> isinstance(add, torch.tensor(1))
False
```

Hence, it will rase `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable` in case you call it.

If you'd like to understand how python double-under methods like **init** or **call** work, you could read this page that describes [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

(It could be a bit tedious, so you could prefer to read something like Fluent Python or other book)

Answer (score 1):

The core thing to remember is that when you *instantiate* a `Module` class, you are creating a callable object, i.e. something that can behave like a function.

In plain English and step by step:

- When you write something like `add5 = Add(5)`, what you are doing is assigning an "instance" of the PyTorch model `Add` to `add5`
- More specifically, you are passing `5` to the `Add` class's `__init__` method, and so its `value` attribute is set to `5`.
- PyTorch `Module`s are "callable" meaning you can call them like functions. The function you call when you use an instance of a `Module` is that instance's `forward` method. So concretely, with our `add5` object, if we pass a value, `x = 10`, by writing something like `add5(10)` it is like we ran `x + add5.value`, which equals `10 + 5 = 15`.

Now putting this together, we should view the `Sequential` interface for building neural network models that don't have branching structures as just *sequentially* invoking each of the instantiated `Module`s' `forward` methods.

Omitting the definition of `Add` and focussing just on `calculator` as a series of computations we have the following (I've added the comments to show you what you should think of at each step)

```py
calculator = nn.Sequential(
            # given some input tensor x...
    Add(3), # run: x = x + self.value with self.value = 3
    Add(2), # run: x = x + self.value with self.value = 2 
    Add(5), # run: x = x + self.value with self.value = 5
)
```

Now we can see that it's reasonable to expect that if we pass the value `1` (albeit wrapped up as a PyTorch `Tensor`) we are just doing `1 + 3 + 2 + 5` which of course equals `11`. PyTorch returns us back the value still as a `Tensor` object.

```py
x = torch.tensor([1])
output = calculator(x)
print(output) # tensor([11])
```

Finally, `Add(3)(5)`* works for exactly this same reason! With `Add(3)` we are getting an instance of the `Add` class with the value to add being 3. We then use it immediately with the somewhat unintuitive syntax `Add(3)(5)` to return the value `3 + 5 = 8`.

*I think you intended the capitalised *class* name, not an instance of the class

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Have a nice day !